# How to know mail was send or not in zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

i wrote a code for sending email, after successfully send it cant return any status

```
$message = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
    $htmlPart = new MimePart($body);
    $htmlPart->type = "text/html";

    $textPart = new MimePart($body);
    $textPart->type = "text/plain";

    $body = new MimeMessage();
    $body->setParts(array($textPart, $htmlPart));

    $message->setBody( $body );
    $message->setFrom('it.test.com');
    $message->addTo( $this->to ); // $message->addTo($RequesterEmailAddr);
    $message->setSubject( $this->subject );
    $message->getHeaders()->get('content-type')->setType('multipart/alternative');
    $smtpOptions = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions();  
    $smtpOptions->setHost('smtp.test.com')
                ->setConnectionClass('login')
                ->setName('smtp.test.com')
                ->setConnectionConfig(array(
                    'username' => $this->Username_Email,
                    'password' => $this->Password_Email,
                    'ssl' => 'tls',
                    'port' => 25,
                ));
    $transport  = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp($smtpOptions);
    $MailStatus = $transport->send($message) ;

$MailStatus
```

above variable returning nothing after successfully send email
Plase help me

Answer (score 0):

it s normal because the send method doesn't return anything 
but you can check if something went wrong 'Transport\File and Transport\Smtp throw an Exception\RuntimeException when something goes wrong. The File transporter does this, for example, when it can not write the file.'